# Can't receive call if app sent through Test flight or ad hoc

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm trying to develop two iOS Apps that can share calls.

using twillio sdk everything is working fine as expected,

App A should be able to call App B,

App B should be able to only receive calls from App A,

I submitted the two apps on testflight and they were accepted

App A is working perfect

but concerning app B if i run it through xocde it works perfect, while if I downloaded it from testflight it doesnt recieve any call,

I also tried generating an adhoc certificate and send the app to my device using [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) but it also doesn't work.

can anyone help me in resloving this issue, any advice may help in my case.

Does anyone knows any needed entitlement that should be fixed in order to receive a call.

Comment: Is there any more detail you can give about App B not receiving calls? Is it correctly retrieving a access token to initialize the Twilio Voice SDK with? Does it throw any errors when you initiate a call to it? How do you know App A is working perfectly if App B doesn't receive any calls?

Comment: Hello @philnash 
- yes, I made sure that it's correctly receiving a voip token, and it's being initialize with Twilio SDK
- no , it doesn't throw any error.
- App B doesn't receive any calls if I distribute it on TestFlight , but if I run it on any device from xcode, it functions perfectly.
- probably the issue is from the certificates, I may need a specific certificate for distributing the app.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't think I can help with certificate issues, my experience doesn't stretch that far. Is the issue that your app won't receive incoming notifications? Have you supplied Twilio with the certificates for sending notifications for your TestFlight configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it turned out that the issue was in the VoIP certificate (p12 file) provided for the backend server-side, I never switched it to release. I kept it on development. once I tried switching it to release after release on testflight. everything worked perfectly.